# How should Quoted-Printable Mime-Words be wrapped to the correct line length?

Tags: smtp, mime, rfc5322

I ran into a [bug](https://github.com/andris9/mimelib/issues/6) in a mime parsing library where it blows up on subject lines that contain foreign characters beyond a certain length.  It turns out that it would convert the subject into a Quoted-Printable MIME "[Encoded-Word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word)" and then try to word-wrap the whole thing to 78 characters.  Because MIME-Word encoding has no spaces (they are replaced with underscores) it failed to wrap.

Example line being wrapped:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?lalalla_=E7=84=A1=E6=AD=A4=E7=84=A1=E6=AD=A4=E9=A0=85=E7=9B=AE=AE=AE=AE=AE=AE=AE=AE=AE?=
```

I thought I might contribute a patch to the library to wrap the line correctly but I couldn't find a reference as to how to break up a MIME-Word as part of a word-wrapping algorithm.

The [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2.3) says to word-wrap at spaces but doesn't provide any guidance about what to do if there's a string of characters with no white-space that exceeds the target width.

Anyone know the correct action to take here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split the line where you need to, and continue with a 2nd wrapped line. For example:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?lalalla_=E7=84=A1=E6=AD=A4=E7=84=A1=E6=AD=A4?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?=E9=A0=85=E7=9B=AE=AE=AE=AE=AE=AE=AE=AE=AE?=
```

Just be sure to make sure the 2nd (and following) wrapped lines start with either a space or a tab.

hth,
--Dave

Comment: So, it looks like what you are doing is decoding the Mime-Word, then doing some kind of splitting/word-wrapping, and re-encoding it?  Or perhaps detecting splitting the mime-word at an arbitrary even triple and sticking \r\n\t=?UTF-8?Q? in as the separator?

Comment: you should be able to split the line any place.Just make sure you begin and end the line correctly.